# PIR (HC SR-501) not working

Tags: esp8266, low-voltage, pir

I'm working with ESP8266 Wemos D1 Mini and HC SR-501 (PIR sensor) in one particular project (please, see the circuit image in annex). The question is the HC SR-501 stay always LOW. I tried change the PIR Sensor by ultrasonic sensor (HC SR-04) and the circuit works fine (obviously, little things was changed)!
Why this circuit not work with PIR sensor? Could be the PIR sensor with some problem?
PS: i used two PIR sensor and both not work.

Thank your for help.[image]

Comment: Please add links to the datasheets so that we don't all have to search for them.

Comment: The pir sensor works if you disconnect the output form esp8266? Check with a voltmeter. Have you set D2 as input?

Comment: I do see a 1k resistor in series with the output on the HC SR-501. This is not present on HC SR04 that means it has a better current capability. That could explain why one is working and the other not if you forgot to set D2 as input or some peripheral has the control or a pull-down is activated.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

*Figure 1. Extract from the [PIR datasheet](https://www.mpja.com/download/31227sc.pdf).*

The datasheet shows that the device is 3.3 V. You are feeding it into 5 V logic so you need a level shifter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUTMJC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. A simple level-shifter.*

If you enable the pull-ups on your micro's inputs then you may omit R2. Note that the circuit inverts the logic from the PIR.

Notes on your schematic:

- In general the high voltage rails should be on the top of the schematic and the lower voltages towards the bottom. It makes it much easier to read.
- Use one ground symbol for each point that is grounded. This reduces clutter and clearly shows the voltage at that point without having to trace back to the PSU.

---

> 1) I'm feeding the PIR with a 5 vdc. Note that 3.3v logic is the output signal of the sensor, and send 0v when not body detect and 3.3v when body detect. In the most examples on the web, i don't see the people using resistors and/or transistors, because the 3.3v is the same I/O voltage that ESP8266 operate.

[image]

*Figure 2. The PIR datasheet clearly shows that the whole circuit is fed from a [7133-1](http://www.bookly.com/images/BM71xx.pdf) voltage regulator. This is a low drop-out 3.3 V regulator. The maximum PIR output voltage will be 3.3 V.*

> 2) In your circuit, what Q1 transistor? It's not clear for me.

Any small-signal NPN transistor will work. 2N2222 is an example.

Comment: Ok Transistor, thanks for your reply. But analysing your post, i perceive two things: 1) I'm feeding the PIR with a 5 vdc. Note that 3.3v logic is the output signal of the sensor, and send 0v when not body detect and 3.3v when body detect. In the most examples on the web, i don't see the people using resistors and/or transistors, because the 3.3v is the same I/O voltage that ESP8266 operate. 2) In your circuit, what Q1 transistor? It's not clear for me. Thank you again for your reply.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Please correct this. The advice of shifting the output to 5V is wrong, and will fry the ESP8266, which notoriously has a 3V3 logic.

Comment: @user156047: In that case it's already fried. OP has it powered from 5 V. I'm not familiar with the board and OP provided no datasheet links. Does it use 3.3 V internally? In any case I think my update should make it clear. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: a quick google search for the wemos schematic, reveals that there is a regulator that takes the 5V down to 3V3. The board is not fried, until you put the level shifter in.
https://wiki.wemos.cc/_media/products:d1:sch_d1_mini_v3.0.0.pdf

Comment: Wemos I/O logic level is at 3V3 indeed.